# Smart trim() option in php and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, regex, clean-urls, code-cleanup

This is the problem that I have in PHP and jQuery.
I want to make a "smart" function that will not only clean white space, but also a certain character at the beginning and end of the string. Why?

I made administration panel who manage with subdomains. Allowed characters is [a-z0-9-.]. If someone accidentally write "**-my.domanin.**" or "**.my-domain**" or "**-my-domain-**" or a similar variation is problem. I need to trim that to look like this "**my-domain**" or "**my.domain**"

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: you can add character mask to `trim()`. See the docs

Comment: Just so you need the dot `.` is not a part of the set `[a-z0-9-]` so `my.domain` is an invalid name. Also, if you want to use regex and substitution [check this out](http://regex101.com/r/tM9pF8/1)

Comment: OK, I forgot to look trim documentation on PHP but jquery don't have mask. Thanks @skamazin this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mytrim($stringToTrim) {
    return trim($tringToTrim, " \t\n\r\0\x0B.-");
}
```

The first part of the string, " \t\n\r\0\x0B", strips white space from the beginning and ends and the second part, ".-" strips the "." and "-" characters.

Clearly you could just use trim() in your script, I just put it in a function for the example.